# Silverlight inheritance like WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend, silverlight-5.0

to minimize the code-lines in WPF all my controls inherit from a style called BaseControlStyle that looks something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

A new Button Style would look like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType={x:Type Button} BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseControlStyle}">
....
</Style>
```

But being new to Silverlight I could not find a answer whether it is possible to transfer this BaseControlStyle to into a SilverlightBaseControlStyle that uses VisualStateManager (or something else) or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such thing as property triggers in Silverlight - Visual States are used instead, which means handling appearance in code. For such tasks as in your case it is easier to create a copy of a standard Button's style and change animations in it's default ControlTemplate.
Sometimes it is also useful to use [behaviors](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I've done some research myself and couldn't find another answer. So unfortunately it seems that there is no better way than copying the control template. But I'm definitely considering using behaviors for some more complex stuff. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Yeah, behaviors sometimes could be really helpful! Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, silverlight does not support this type of use:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
```